# Storing only SubItem from ListView to a .bat file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have made a software that creates a .bat files that hide a particular file.

When this button 'HideItBtn' is clicked, it creats a .bat file and that .bat file have the file location - 'strArray' - which is stored as subItem in a ListView !

```
private void HideItBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string[] strArray = new string[500];
    int i = 0;

    StreamWriter hide = new StreamWriter(HideNameTxt.Text + ".bat");
    hide.WriteLine("@Echo off");
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem cur in FolderList.Items[i].SubItems)
    {
        strArray[i] = cur.Text;
        hide.WriteLine("attrib \"" + strArray[i] + "\" +s +h");

        i++;
    }

    hide.Close();
}
```

What i am trying to do here is access the subItem But with that the item i.e. "Folder Name" also get written to the .bat file. Here is the output File :

```
@Echo off
attrib "New folder (2)" +s +h
attrib "C:\Users\Sand\Desktop\New folder (2)" +s +h
```

Is there any way to not include the original Item to .bat file? Thanks in Advance! And sorry for bad English !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look through the `SubItems`, the first item is what would be returned by the `Text` of the actual `ListItem`; so you could do this:

```
for (int j = 1; j < FolderList.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
{
    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem cur = FolderList.Items[i].SubItems[j];

    strArray[i] = cur.Text;
    hide.WriteLine("attrib \"" + strArray[i] + "\" +s +h");

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Allot ! That was the last piece of puzzle for my application and u helped me to solve it ! :)